# Can't log in to Django admin locally or in prod

Tags: python, django

I'm having two problems with my new Django admin, but I'm not sure if they're related so I don't want to split them into two questions just yet.

The site is live and working--I went to the admin for the first time and got a csrf error.  So I went back to my dev site and tried to log in, and it told me that my username/password was incorrect.  I did `python manage.py createsuperuser` and still was unable to log in with the new user (credentials were definitely correct).

Here are some of my settings files based on what seemed relevant from other askers.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"
```

Note that the three Boolean values had previously been set to `True`.  I changed them to `False` to experiment, and cleared cookies.  No change.

I also tried an incognito browser to rule out cookies and it still did not work.

Comment: Does your server run HTTP or HTTPS?

Comment: HTTP, I think.  It's Heroku.

Comment: Ok, well you need those set to `False`. You need secure cookies turned on for `HTTPS`, and if `CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY` is set, JS can't access your CSRF cookie so you won't be able to Ajax POST. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#csrf-cookie-httponly

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing expired sessions.

```
python manage.py clearsessions
```